# Use of which() inside of mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using which() to define a new variable inside mutate in the following way.

I have two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
telephone = c("1231231234", "2342342345", "3453453456", "1231231234"),
email = c("a@email.com", "b@email.com", "c@email.com", "d@mail.com")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
phone = c("1231231234", "2342342345", "3453453456")
)
```

What I am attempting to do is add a new variable to df2 that stores each row number in which the value of "phone" occurs in df1$telephone. I have attempted the following:

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
mutate(
phone_ind = str_flatten(which(df1$telephone == phone), collapse = ", ")
)
```

This yields the warning

**Warning message: Problem while computing `phone_ind = str_flatten(which(df1$telephone == phone), collapse = ", ")`.**

**ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length**

as well as the following obviously incorrect results:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
phone = c("1231231234", "2342342345", "3453453456"),
phone_ind = c("1, 2, 3, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4", "1, 2, 3, 4")
)
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr) # v1.1.0
df2 %>%
  left_join(transmute(df1, phone = telephone, row = row_number()), multiple = "all") %>%
  summarize(row = paste(row, collapse = ", "), .by = phone)
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(phone)`
       phone  row
1 1231231234 1, 4
2 2342342345    2
3 3453453456    3
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was hoping for a solution that would work with the pipe operator. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a row number to `df1` first, then join it to `df2` and collapse the row numbers:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  telephone = c("1231231234", "2342342345", "3453453456", "1231231234"),
  email = c("a@email.com", "b@email.com", "c@email.com", "d@mail.com")
)

df2 <- tibble(
  phone = c("1231231234", "2342342345", "3453453456")
)

df1 |> 
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  select(!email) |> 
  right_join(df2, join_by(telephone == phone)) |> 
  summarise(rows = str_flatten(row, collapse = ", "), 
            .by = telephone)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   telephone  rows 
#>   <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 1231231234 1, 4 
#> 2 2342342345 2    
#> 3 3453453456 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R by using `sapply` and `paste` (or just change `paste` to `str_flatten` if you prefer to use the `stringr` package)

```
df2$new <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df2)), function(x) {
  paste(rownames(df1[df1$telephone %in% df2$phone[x],]), collapse = ", ")
})

       phone  new
1 1231231234 1, 4
2 2342342345    2
3 3453453456    3
```